# Mapping the same function to multiple tibbles in a list

Tags: r, purrr, magrittr

I have several tibbles, each of which has different numbers of columns and different column names.  I want to standardize the column names for each to be all lowercase.  This works for an individual tibble:

```
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)

colnames(tbl1) %<>% map(tolower)
```

The column names for the object tbl1 are now all lowercase.

If I put all my tibbles in a list, however, this doesn't work:

```
all_tbls <- list(tbl1, tbl2, tbl3)
all_tbls %<>% map(function(tbl) {colnames(tbl) %<>% map(tolower)})
```

The colnames for the objects tbl1, tbl2, and tbl3 are not changed by this.  The objects in the list all_tbls are now lists of the column names for each tbl, i.e. what you'd get if you applied as.list() to the result of colnames()).

Why is this happening?  Is there a better approach to doing this?  I'd prefer to use tidyverse functions (e.g. map instead of *apply) for consistency with other code, but am open to other solutions.  EDIT:  To be clear, I'd like to be able to work with the original tibble objects, i.e. the desired outcome is for the colnames of tbl1, tbl2, and tbl3 to change.

Other Q&A I looked at and did not find illuminating includes:

- [apply function to elements over a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085110/apply-function-to-elements-over-a-list)
- [R: apply a function to a list of dataframes and save to workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45976304/r-apply-a-function-to-a-list-of-dataframes-and-save-to-workspace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)
all_tbls %<>% map(~set_names(.x,tolower(colnames(.x))))
```

> The objects in the list all_tbls are now lists of the column names for each tbl

Because you're asking `map` to lower the column names and return them as a list

To modify in place we can use `data.table::setnames`, since `data.table` using copy in place against copy by reference.

```
library(data.table)
library(purrr)
map(list(df1,df2),~setnames(.,old = names(.), new = tolower(names(.))))
```

Data

```
df1 <- read.table(text='
A B
1 1',header=TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(text='
C D
2 2',header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

The function you're mapping is returning the column names, you need it to return the actual tibble instead:

```
all_tbls %<>% map(function(tbl) { 
    colnames(tbl) %<>% map(tolower)
    tbl
})
```

Comment: This changes the colnames for the objects in the list, but not the original underlying objects.  (I.e. colnames(tbl1) are still mixed-case, but colnames(all_tbls[[1]]) are now all lowercase.)  Is there a concise way to change the colnames for each of the original objects?

Comment: It's a bit tricky to change objects "in place" in R like you can in Python, and `purrr` is not really designed to do that, it's designed for functional programming where you apply functions and return the transformed objects. The only way I can think of right now would require messing around with `get`/`assign`, which I generally wouldn't recommend.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `purrr::map` and `dplyr::rename_all` :

```
all_tbls <- list(head(iris,2), head(cars,2))

library(tidyverse)
all_tbls %>% map(rename_all, toupper)
# [[1]]
#   SEPAL.LENGTH SEPAL.WIDTH PETAL.LENGTH PETAL.WIDTH SPECIES
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 
# [[2]]
#   SPEED DIST
# 1     4    2
# 2     4   10
#
```